# Sum if same ID1 and ID2 - only once - SQL

Tags: sql, distinct

I have the following data on SQL

| EntryID | PersonID | JobID | JobSalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 270000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 500000 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 320000 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 180000 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 320000 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 85000 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 270000 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 500000 |
| 9 | 2 | 3 | 320000 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 180000 |

For each entry, I want to have a column that calculates the total salary (of all jobs) of the specific person.
The tricky part is that multiple entries can refer to the same person and/or the same job, but I only want to sum up each job for each person once.

The output would be:

| EntryID | PersonID | JobID | JobSalary | PersonTotalSalaryAllJobs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 270000 | 855000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 500000 | 855000 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 320000 | 320000 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 180000 | 180000 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 320000 | 320000 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 85000 | 855000 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 270000 | 855000 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 500000 | 855000 |
| 9 | 2 | 3 | 320000 | 320000 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 180000 | 180000 |

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want you can use a query like this

```
SELECT 
    s.*,
    pjts.total_salary
FROM salary s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(jobsalary) OVER (PARTITION BY personid) AS total_salary
    FROM (    
        SELECT DISTINCT
            personid,
            jobid,
            jobsalary
        FROM salary
    )  pjs
) pjts ON s.personid = pjts.personid AND s.jobid = pjts.jobid
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c20ab6a1d92e708926dd05937e91a98)

---

Or even simplier using only one subquery like this

```
SELECT 
    s.*,
    pjts.total_salary
FROM salary s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        personid,
        jobid,
        SUM(jobsalary) OVER (PARTITION BY personid) AS total_salary
    FROM salary
    GROUP BY personid, jobid, jobsalary
) pjts ON s.personid = pjts.personid AND s.jobid = pjts.jobid
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90c7f3b9930f44b15cb80431ab76512c)